# watch OS 2 beacon monitoring and ranging

Tags: ios, watchkit, ibeacon, apple-watch, watchos-2

has anybody found any information about interacting (ranging and monitoring) with Beacons in native Watch OS 2 applications?
I would like to give the user the possibility to range one in an home environment without having the phone in their pocket.
I can't find any docs anywhere and I am wondering if it's actually feasible - and obviously if there is any kind of example around.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Location on watchOS is stripped of all the iBeacon functionality. There are no `startRangingBeaconsInRegion:` and `startMonitoringForRegion:` methods, as can be seen in the CLLocationManager reference documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/

The only option for now is to do the ranging/monitoring on the iPhone, and pass the results to the Watch app via the [Watch Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WCSession).

**UPDATE** for watchOS 4: still no iBeacon in Core Location, but there's now Core Bluetooth available for the watchOS apps, which means your app can detect non-iBeacon packets, such as Eddystone, or Estimote's Nearable/Telemetry.

Only if your app is in the foreground or has execution time though. The latter meaning that, for example, if your app is already running in the background because you're using the new "location updates" background mode for turn-by-turn navigation, or you're tracking workouts in the background, then you can at the same time scan for beacons. In and on itself, detecting Bluetooth beacons won't keep your app alive in the background, it will get suspended.

Comment: Has anything changed for this answer with watchOS 4?

Comment: I updated the answer with the latest watchOS 4 changes.

Answer (score 0):

directly use watch to monitor/ranging with watchOS is prohibited by Apple (it detailed in developer document). It mean you can not turn bluetooth on watch and start monitoring directly! But there're another way, you can integrate app with watchOS, I gave a tried before with our app and it work pretty good. We're using Estimote, you can refer right here: [Estimote Watch SDK Integration](https://github.com/Estimote/Estimote-WatchKit-SDK)

It can be transport notification from iOS device to watch. They provide several helpers support that. Good luck!

Comment: Thx, but I am looking for a solution for the scenario where the user can leave his phone somewhere in his home, and ranging beacons only by wearing the watch

Comment: well! maybe we have to wait when Apple support all functionalities of Core Location on Watch. I'm waiting for it too, Apple should let watch more free and acts independent. You know, now WatchOS is depend mostly on iOS device. Cheer!